# Windows 7 taskbar tabbed thumbnails in .Net 2 application

Tags: .net, winapi, windows-7, .net-2.0, taskbar

How I can handle the windows 7 taskbar to get an effect like the image from a .Net 2 based application?

[image: Example]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check out this project: [Windows® API Code Pack for Microsoft® .NET Framework](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack)**

It's an attempt to wrap the functions exposed in newer versions of the native Windows API so that you can call them easily from a managed .NET application. Specifically, it supports "Jump Lists, Icon Overlay, Progress Bar, Tabbed Thumbnails, and Thumbnail Toolbars" for the new Windows 7 taskbar.

Unfortunately, you won't be able to use the library *directly* from your .NET 2.0 application, as it requires a minimum version of 3.5 SP1. But you could certainly download the project and check out the code that they've used to implement the features, then write the P/Invoke definitions yourself. I can't think of anything that would prevent you from doing this in version 2.0 of the Framework.